# Pass an Object from Angularjs to MVC controller and map to Class Object

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an object in angularjs which I want to pass and map it to custom c# class in mvc controller. but whenever I am doing this class object is null completely.

```
 $scope.Get = function () {
        var EService = [{
            id: $scope.Id,
            servicename: $scope.ServiceName,
            servicetype: $scope.ServiceType,
            monthlyrental: $scope.MonthlyRental,
            serviceremarks: $scope.ServiceRemarks,
            servicestatus: $scope.status,
            activationdate: $scope.ActivationDate,
            deactivationdate: $scope.DeActivationDate
        }];

        $http.post('/TS/API/Insert', Service).then(function (res) {
            debugger;
        })
```

MVC Controller and Class:

```
[HttpPost] 
    public string Insert(ServicesMaster Service)
    {

        GIBCADBEntities gfientity = new GIBCADBEntities();

        var record = "Sent"
        return Json(record, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); 
    } public class ServicesMaster
{
    public string id { set; get; }
    public string servicename { set; get; }
    public string servicetype { set; get; }
    public int? monthlyrental { set; get; }
    public string serviceremarks { set; get; }
    public byte servicestatus { set; get; }
    public DateTime? activationdate { set; get; }
    public DateTime? deactivationdate { set; get; }
}
```

The javascript variable/object "EService" is ok here, and when passing only the ServicesMaster object is created with null values and no data is mapped to it. I can send single string or any value from here but when sending a complete object its behaving like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing an array from front end and fetching object from server end. just remove the "[" and "]" brace while set value to EService . Like :

```
 $scope.Get = function () {
     var Service = {};
     Service = {
        id: $scope.Id,
        servicename: $scope.ServiceName,
        servicetype: $scope.ServiceType,
        monthlyrental: $scope.MonthlyRental,
        serviceremarks: $scope.ServiceRemarks,
        servicestatus: $scope.status,
        activationdate: $scope.ActivationDate,
        deactivationdate: $scope.DeActivationDate
     };

     $http.post('/TS/API/Insert', Service).then(function (res) {
        debugger;

     }); 
};
```

It should work now. :)